# Reverse geocoding (country) from geofield with coordinates

Tags: 7, location

is there a quick way to do a reverse geocoding from a geofield field containing geographical coordinates?

I just need the country name, so I wonder if there is some service with more allowance than the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=it#ReverseGeocoding), or even a hosted solution with country coordinates and a drupal module quering it???? (as it seems to be a Drupal module for everything)

Comment: [MapQuest Nominatim](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) can handle reverse geocoding and I don't think it has a usage limit at the moment. The geofield module has integration with that service but I'm not sure if there's a UI/method exposed for reverse-coding. Might be worth a look

Answer (score 2):

this is a question that I asked to myself some time ago. I suggest to start from the [geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module.
This module "translate" an address to a lat./lon. parameter that could be displayed in a map.
Reversing this process - if I understand correctly your question - seems to be a WIP: actually, no out-of-the-box solution.
But you can check and try the suggestions in this [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1461164).